# MySQL query to dynamic "Ranking rows"

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I'm having problems running a query ranking.
The inner SELECT gives the rows in order of ranking, for each line, the variable @rank increases, if not a position equal to the previous ranking.
But the @rank is not really the correct position.

I'm trying to do a ranking grouped and ordered by those with the highest value.

```
SET @prev := NULL;
SET @curr := NULL;
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT
    @prev := @curr,
    @curr := SUM( a.value ) AS SUM_VALUES,
    @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank,
    b.id AS b_id,
    b.name AS b_nome

FROM
    a INNER JOIN b ON ( a.b_id = b.id )

GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY SUM_VALUES DESC;
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------------------------
@prev := @curr | SUM_VALUES | rank | b_id  | b_nome
---------------|------------|------|-------|--------
NULL           | 10         | 2    | 2     | BBB
NULL           | 2          | 1    | 1     | AAA
```

Here BBB was to return in the first place in the ranking and AAA, second in ranking.
But this does not occur, one idea of what is happening?

---

A test dump

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `b_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `value` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `b_id` (`b_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_b` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'BBB');

INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `b_id`, `value`, `name`) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 'smaller');
INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `b_id`, `value`, `name`) VALUES (2, 2, 10, 'bigger');
```

Comment: What is the result that you *want*?  That's not really clear.  Also it can help to simplify your example to a really simple data set that demonstrates your issue without a bunch of tables, columns, and filters irrelevant to the question.  There's too much to process in this question which is probably why you haven't gotten any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**having**
It will be slow, but a `having` clause will run **after** all the selects, joins, where and group by's have finished and are fully resolved.
The only problem is that `having` does not use an index, whilst `where` does use an index.

```
SELECT
  ranking stuff
FROM 
  lot of tables
WHERE simple_condition
HAVING filters_that_run_last
```

**Make your joins explicit**
Note that you don't have to mix explicit and implicit joins.
If you **want** a cross join, you can use the `cross join` keyword.

```
    ....
    ) AS Ranking
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) InitVars
WHERE
  Ranking.regional_id = 1003
```

Comment: Thank you. Take a look as I did to bring the expected result ... =P...Again, thank you

Answer (score 2):

**First, Thank you all!**

I found a way to return the expected result making other selects 2

**A)** Select first grouped and ordered

```
SELECT
    SUM( a.value ) AS SUM_VALUES,
    b.id AS b_id,
    b.name AS b_name
FROM
    a INNER JOIN b ON ( a.b_id = b.id )
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY SUM_VALUES DESC
```

**B)** I do this ranking list

```
SELECT
    R.*,
   @prev := @curr,
   @curr := R.SUM_VALUES,
   @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM (
        SELECT
            SUM( a.value ) AS SUM_VALUES,
            b.id AS b_id,
            b.name AS b_name
        FROM
            a INNER JOIN b ON ( a.b_id = b.id )
        GROUP BY b.id
        ORDER BY SUM_VALUES DESC
) AS R
```

**C)** And lastly, just select what matters

```
SELECT
    Ranking.b_id,
    Ranking.b_name,
    Ranking.rank
FROM
(
    SELECT
        R.*,
       @prev := @curr,
       @curr := R.SUM_VALUES,
       @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
    FROM (
            SELECT
                SUM( a.value ) AS SUM_VALUES,
                b.id AS b_id,
                b.name AS b_name
            FROM
                a INNER JOIN b ON ( a.b_id = b.id )
            GROUP BY b.id
            ORDER BY SUM_VALUES DESC
    ) AS R
) AS Ranking
WHERE
    Ranking.b_id = 1
```

The result of this query was:

```
+------+--------+------+
| b_id | b_name | rank |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 | AAA    |    2 |
+------+--------+------+
```