# MySQL row select increments only when results aren't the same

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to rank points from a SQL select however only when the points aren't tied with other points in the returned results.

The SQL Query that I am using:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank FROM points;
```

Quite simple!
And it displays the following results:

```
id | user_id | points | rank
----------------------------
2  | 133845  | 220    | 1
3  | 134084  | 220    | 2
4  |      1  | 150    | 3
5  | 134086  | 145    | 4
6  | 134080  | 100    | 5
7  |  17938  |  30    | 6
8  |  83011  |  20    | 7
9  |     26  |   5    | 8
10 | 134077  |   5    | 9
11 | 134074  |   5    | 10
```

As you can see ID 2 and 3 have the same amount of points and so does ID 9, 10 , and 11. So technically the rank should be the same for all of them rather than continuing to increment.

This example below is how the table should properly look:

```
id | user_id | points | rank
----------------------------
2  | 133845  | 220    | 1
3  | 134084  | 220    | 1
4  |      1  | 150    | 2
5  | 134086  | 145    | 3
6  | 134080  | 100    | 4
7  |  17938  |  30    | 5
8  |  83011  |  20    | 7
9  |     26  |   5    | 8
10 | 134077  |   5    | 8
11 | 134074  |   5    | 8
```

I realize that continuously incrementing the rank (using @rank+1) per row on the select isn't the ideal way to do this. So how would I go about specifcally incrementing only when the points are different?

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840745/mysql-query-to-dynamic-ranking-rows#answer-7854813): `@rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the working solution end up being:

```
SET @rank=0;
SET @curr=0;
SELECT *, 
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := points.points,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM points;
```

Thanks much for leading me into the right direction George!